# Clarification request for initial differentiation of $y=e^{-x^2}\int_0^xe^{t^2}dt+c_1e^{-x^2}$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

I am attempting to differentiate $y=e^{-x^2}\int_0^xe^{t^2}dt+c_1e^{-x^2}$ wrt x

My solution manual says that the answer is

$y'=e^{-x^2}e^{x^2}-2xe^{-x^2}\int_0^xe^{t^2}dt-2c_1xe^{-x^2}$

When I initially performed this operation myself, I wound up with

$y'=-2xe^{-x^2}\int_0^xe^{t^2}dt-2c_1xe^{-x^2}$

treating the  $\int_0^xe^{t^2}dt$ as a constant.

Can anyone clarify for me where the $e^{-x^2}e^{x^2}$ came from? There must be a product rule that I am just missing to have that third term involved right?

Edit: Taking Josh's suggestion, if I treat $\int_0^xe^{t^2}dt$ as another x-term, as I rightly should have, then use a product rule, I should end up at the solution manual's step.

Differentiating $e^{-x^2}\int_0^xe^{t^2}dt$ wrt x

$(\frac{d}{dx}e^{-x^2})(\int_0^xe^{t^2}dt)+(\frac{d}{dx}\int_0^xe^{t^2}dt)(e^{-x^2})$

Now I'm stuck on trying to integrate this in so that I can differentiate it in terms of x.

$\int_0^xe^{t^2}dt$

Also, thank you to Shaun, I did not know that MathJax worked in the title

Comment: Don't treat $\int\limits_0^ x e^{t^2}dt$ as a constant. Viewing $y$ as a function of $x$, this term changes as $x$ changes. Then use the fundamental theorem of calculus.

Comment: MathJax works in the title, don't you know?

Comment: Don't try to integrate the term, the fundamental theorem of calculus tells you that if $f$ is a continuous real-valued function defined on $(a,b)$, then for $x\in [a,b]$, if $F(x) = \int\limits_a^x f(t)dt$, then $F'(x)  =f(x)$.

Comment: Please forgive my timelyness, I've been through Calc 3 and still don't feel like I have a good grasp on a number of things. If I'm undestanding this correctly, then $\int_a^xf(t)dt$ would result in $F(x)-F(a)$, which, if this was then differentiated with respect to $x$, would cause $F(a)$ to go to 0, since it is a constant and would cause $F(x)$ to become $f(x)$ essentially reversing the integration that was just performed, leaving me with, in this case $e^{x^2}$

Comment: $\int_0^x e^{t^2} \ dt$ does not integrate into elementary functions.  It becomes $\frac {\sqrt \pi}{2} \text{erfi} (x)$ ...an imaginary error function.  http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Erfi.html

As this is probably not something you have discussed in class, just leave it the way it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$y=e^{-x^2}\int_0^xe^{t^2}dt+c_1e^{-x^2}$$

We have
\begin{align}
y' &= \left(\frac{d}{dx}e^{-x^2}\right)\left(\int_0^xe^{t^2}\,dt\right)+\left(\frac{d}{dx}\int_0^xe^{t^2}\,dt\right)\left(e^{-x^2}\right) + c_1 \frac{d}{dx} \exp(-x^2) \\
&= \left(-2xe^{-x^2}\right)\left(\int_0^xe^{t^2}\,dt\right)+\left(e^{x^2}\right)\left(e^{-x^2}\right) -2x c_1 \exp(-x^2) \\
&= \left(e^{x^2}\right)\left(e^{-x^2}\right)-2xe^{-x^2}\int_0^xe^{t^2}\,dt -2x c_1 \exp(-x^2)\\
&= 1-2xe^{-x^2}\int_0^xe^{t^2}\,dt -2 c_1 x \exp(-x^2) \\
&= 1-2x\exp(-x^2) \left(\int_0^xe^{t^2}\, dt + c_1 \right)
\end{align}

Notice that the solution manual didn't simplify $e^{-x^2}e^{x^2}=1$.